# Acumatica - Add Notes to AP Bills and AR Invoices programatically

Tags: acumatica

I'm creating AP Bills and AR Invoices programatically. For some of those documents, I want to add some notes. I'm using the following line of code to acheive that:

> PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(graph.CurrentDocument.Cache, apInvoice, "My
>   notes"); graph.Actions.PressSave();

However this does not add the Notes to the document. 
apInvoice above is of type APInvoice. The NoteID field is in APRegister DAC but APInvoice inherits that field. I also tried using APRegister type of object but still it does not add the Notes. Are there any additional steps required that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be missing a dataview update:

```
PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(graph.CurrentDocument.Cache, apInvoice, "My notes");
graph.CurrentDocument.Update(apInvoice);
graph.Actions.PressSave();
```

Maybe CurrentDocument.Cache is not a Cache of APInvoice type:

```
PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(graph.Caches[typeof(APInvoice)], apInvoice, "My notes");
graph.Caches[typeof(APInvoice)].PersistUpdated(apInvoice);
```

Comment: It still does not save the Notes. I also tried by using APRegister.

Comment: Are you still having issues? If so, can you add more of your code in your question?